# Using ray tune `tune.run` with pytorch returns different optimal hyperparameters combination

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, hyperparameters, ray-tune

I've initialized two identical ANN with PyTorch (both as structure and initial parameters), and I've noticed that the hyperparameters setting with Ray Tune, returns different results for the two ANN, even if I didn't have any random initialization.

Someone could explain what I'm doing wrong? I'll attach the code:

- ANN Initialization:

```
class Featrues_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, dim_hidden, n_outputs):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_inputs, dim_hidden)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(dim_hidden, n_outputs)
    
    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.fc1(X)
        X = self.fc2(X)
        return X

features_model_v1 = Featrues_model(len(list_input_variables),5,6)
features_model_v2 = Featrues_model(len(list_input_variables),5,6)


features_model_v2.load_state_dict(features_model_v1.state_dict())
```

- Hyperpamameters setting

```
config = {
    "lr": tune.choice([1e-2, 1e-5]),
    "weight_decay": tune.choice([1e-2, 1e-5]),
    "batch_size": tune.choice([16,64]),
    "epochs": tune.choice([10,50])
}
```

- Train & Validation Dataframe

```
trainset = df_final.copy()

test_abs = int(len(trainset) * 0.8)
train_subset, val_subset = random_split(
    trainset, [test_abs, len(trainset) - test_abs]
)

df_train = df_final.iloc[train_subset.indices]
df_val = df_final.iloc[val_subset.indices]
```

- Train function design

```
def setting_model(config, df_train, df_val, model):
    
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=config["lr"], weight_decay=config["weight_decay"])
    BATCH_SIZE = config["batch_size"]
    
    for epoch in range(config["epochs"]):
        train_epoch_loss = 0
        train_epoch_acc = 0
        step = 0
        
        for i in tqdm(range(0, df_train.shape[0], BATCH_SIZE)):

            batch_X = np.array(
                df_train[list_input_variables].iloc[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]
            )
            
            batch_X = torch.Tensor([x for x in batch_X])

            batch_Y = np.array(
                df_train[list_output_variables].iloc[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]
            )
            batch_Y = torch.Tensor([int(y) for y in batch_Y])
            batch_Y = batch_Y.type(torch.int64)

            optimizer.zero_grad() 
          
            outputs = model.forward(batch_X)
           
            train_loss = criterion(outputs, batch_Y)    
            train_acc = multi_acc(outputs, batch_Y)
            
            train_loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
  
            train_epoch_loss += train_loss.item()
            train_epoch_acc += train_acc.item()
            step += 1

        # print statistics
        print(f"Epochs: {epoch}")
        print(f"Train Loss: {train_epoch_loss/len(df_train)}")
        print(f"Train Acc: {train_epoch_acc/step}")
        print("\n")
            

        # Validation loss
        with torch.no_grad():

            X_val = np.array(
                df_val[list_input_variables]
            )
            X_val = torch.Tensor([x for x in X_val])

            Y_val = np.array(
                df_val[list_output_variables]
            )
            Y_val = torch.Tensor([int(y) for y in Y_val])
            Y_val = Y_val.type(torch.int64)

            outputs = model.forward(X_val)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            
            total = Y_val.size(0)
            correct = (predicted == Y_val).sum().item()
            
            loss = criterion(outputs, Y_val)

        tune.report(loss=(loss.numpy()), accuracy=correct / total)
        
    print(f"Validation Loss: {loss.numpy()/len(df_val)}")
    print(f"Validation Acc: {correct / total:.3f}")
    
    print("Finished Training")
```

- Hyperparameters Tune

```
result_v1 = tune.run(
    partial(setting_model, df_train=df_train, df_val=df_val, model=features_model_v1),
    config=config,
    fail_fast="raise",
)

result_v2 = tune.run(
    partial(setting_model, df_train=df_train, df_val=df_val, model=features_model_v2),
    config=config,
    fail_fast="raise"
)
```

- Output

```
result_v1.get_best_config()
{'lr': 1e-05, 'weight_decay': 1e-05, 'epochs': 1}
result_v2.get_best_config()
{'lr': 0.01, 'weight_decay': 1e-05, 'epochs': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of torch.random under the hood. Since you are not directly providing a weight matrix for your layers, pytorch initializes it for you. Luckily, you can have a reproducible experiment by setting

```
torch.manual_seed(x) # where x is an integer
```

One should use only a few random seeds, otherwise you might overfit on the random seed. See lottery ticket hypothesis at https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03635)